# Run .bat file using getrealpath method?

Tags: java, batch-file, servlets

Greeings,
I m trying to run a .bat file using servlet.if I give static path the bat file is executed but instead of staic path when I use getRealPath method .bat file dont execute and it also dont show the error? 
My Code is:

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        String path="/batfile.bat";
        String blastpath=servletContext.getRealPath(path);
        System.out.println(blastpath);
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = run.exec(blastpath);
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of ```System.out.println(blastpath);```

Comment: It showing the path of bat file